# Is there a tool like DbgCLR.exe which could be used to debug .NET Framework 4.0 assemblies

Tags: .net, debugging

It seems DbgClr does not exist in .NET 4.0, is there any other similar tools

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WinDbg might be a good choice.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463009

Comment: WinDbg is good, but it has quite the learning curve.  Keep in mind the command `.loadby sos clr`  That will allow you to debug the CLR aspect of your program, otherwise you will only be able to debug the native code.  Also, look around for a WinDbg Sos cheat sheet.  That will help as well.